# Best way to combine information from different models

Tags: modeling, prediction

I have 3 models using different methods for the same outcome and predictor variables of a training set. I can apply these models to a new test dataset for predicting outcome variable. Is it a good idea to take average of the outcome variable predicted by these 3 models? It seems that 'ensemble learning' deals with combining multiple models to get better prediction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ensemble_learning). What are the drawbacks of simple averaging of predicted values? Which other method(s) are easy to implement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are predicting continuous values, averaging is a common method. Of course you should try another methods (like take max, min, value with smallest CI, ..).

If your models are classifiers, there are a lot of other methods, except averaging (raw propensity averaging). Most common are voting and confidence-weighted voting.

If you know the performance of your models, it would be useful to make weighted averaging. I mean:
$$
{A\cdot P_1 + B\cdot P_2 + C\cdot P_3}\over{A+B+C}
$$
where $P_{1..3}$ is your model's prediction, and $A, B, C$ are the weight coefficients. To find these weight coefficients, you can use confidence of each prediction.

Sometimes it is better to use one model on specific parts of data, one on another, etc...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you explain a bit more about how to get values for weights A,B and C.